# Can we code a hold key function in a vb script

Tags: vbscript

I want to make a vbs script to do a window toggle.
so this is the keystroke
hold alt + tab

but still keep holding tab
But I still want the alt button to be pressed down so after i navigate to the correct window i'll say enter which will have a key stroke, enter and to release any held down buttons.

So how can i write a key stroke for holding down and for releasing separately

I don't mid if you give me a  keybd_event function user32 dll script(plz give a little more detail if so)

Comment: Quite sure you can't do this in vbscript... you can send keys but can't specify to keep a key depressed.

Comment: Can you tell me a way to do it by keybd_event function user32 dll

Comment: You should be able to simulate this with `SendKeys` using smaller `Sleep` in between.

Comment: How do write that in code???

Comment: You can find basic sendKeys information here. How you try to stop could be interesting. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5169.vbscript-sendkeys-method.aspx

Comment: keybd_event function user32 dll is a better way to hold keys. can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score -1):

To specify that a combination of SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT should be held down while several other keys are pressed, create a compound string argument with the modified keystrokes enclosed in parentheses. For example, to send the keystroke combination that specifies that the SHIFT key is held down while:

e and c are pressed, send the string argument "+(ec)".

e is pressed, followed by a lone c (with no SHIFT), send the string argument "+ec".

From Sendkeys Help.

There is also AppActivate

Activates an application window.

```
object.AppActivate title
```

Also ToggleDesktop Method

---

Raises and lowers the desktop.

Syntax

```
IShellDispatch4.ToggleDesktop()
```

Comment: the other keys i press are not determined. i just want to keep the alt pressed down till i give the command to release

Comment: Turn on sticky keys. Press Alt twice to turn on, press whatever you want, press Alt to turn off. Experiment with that. It's not clear what you are trying to do. You are saying you solution doesn't work but not the problem.

Comment: If you want to keybd_event you need to use vb.net.